# Fetch data from Strapi Api and Pass it through MDX

Tags: next.js, strapi, next.js13, mdxjs

Is it possible to Fetch data from Strapi API and pass it through MDX in order to use MDX Components features?

Comment: Take a look at [mdx-remote](https://github.com/hashicorp/next-mdx-remote).